# Adding InkPicture programmatically to a word document

Tags: python, ms-word, activex

I'm trying to add MSINKAUTLib.InkPicture to an existing word document using python, so far i have failed finding any documentation about that. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i mis-spelled the namespace, should be ***msinkaut.InkPicture.1***